# Python: os.environ KeyError after export

Tags: python, environment-variables, keyerror

Why python can't get evironment variable after export?
How to fix this?

```
λ: export AUTOTEST=/home/anton/eltx/scripts/gitlab/
~
λ: python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['AUTOTEST']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'AUTOTEST'
>>> 
>>> os.environ.get('AUTOTEST', 'none_value')
'none_value'
>>>
```

Comment: Did you launch Python from the same shell where you exported the variable?

Comment: Can't reproduce. This works fine for me.

Comment: Could it happen that your `python` is aliased? What do you get when you issue: `which python`?

Comment: Works for me. You're either not actually exporting the var or you are running python from some other shell instance. You've clearly left out a crucial detail from your problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. There was an alias for running python